# How to do wildcard bean mapping in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do RESTful URL mapping in Spring 2.5. This essentially means:
/fetch/(something)
should all be matched to controller fetch

And the controller will do something according the parameter (something)

I add this to my spring config:

```
<bean id="fetchController" class="(package).fetchController" scope="singleton"/>

<bean id="fetchService" class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
    <property name="mappings">
        <props>
            <prop key="/fetch/*">fetchController</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>
```

and add the following to my `web.xml`

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springGlobal</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fetch/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>

<servlet>
    <servlet-name>springGlobal</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
```

But this doesn't seem to be correct. The log says:
org.springframework.web.servlet.PageNotFound  - No mapping found for HTTP request with URI [/fetch/charts] in DispatcherServlet with name 'springGlobal'

Comment: Off-topic: please consider upgrading to `3.2`. Version `4.0` is on its way as well.

Comment: I wish I could but this is not something I have control of.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Controller handler mappings are resolved relative to the servlet mapping. What you have is therefore mapped to

```
/fetch/fetch/*
```

You should use

```
<property name="mappings">
    <props>
        <prop key="/*">fetchController</prop>
    </props>
</property>
```

Comment: Wait a minute...What if I have another controller should be mapped to /status/*. Then in this case I would have two controllers with prop key="/*". How does spring know which one it should pick?

Comment: I'm not sure with 2.5, but it should choose the most specific one. What you can also do is make your `DispatcherServlet` map to `/*` and have separate controllers `/fetch/*`, `/status/*`.

Comment: That works though I'm still looking into this to see how to make it better. Thanks.

Comment: @NSF I will refer you back to my original comment :).